# Unable to see CPU temps for new AMD Ryzen 7700x

Tags: linux, cpu, kernel, temperature, amd-ryzen

I have the following problem with a new PC.
Linux Mint was installed on a PC (data see code block), but I can not display the CPU temperature in any way.

```
╭─user@machine03153 ~ 
╰─$ sudo inxi -Fxz        
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.5 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: N/A
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING X670E-PLUS v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0821 date: 11/15/2022
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 7700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3
    rev: 2 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 8 MiB L3: 32 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2919 high: 3002 min/max: 400/5573 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 2923 2: 2951 3: 2959 4: 2767 5: 3002 6: 2933 7: 2960 8: 2954 9: 2958
    10: 2956 11: 2752 12: 2896 13: 2968 14: 2893 15: 2892 16: 2954
    bogomips: 143994
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    vendor: Sapphire Nitro+ driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-2: AMD vendor: ASUSTeK driver: N/A bus-ID: 11:00.0
```

And this is the output of `sudo sensors-detect`

```
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No
```

After some research I found out that I must have the module k10temp loaded, I checked that with `sudo modinfo k10temp`. So it seems like k10temp is already loaded?

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/k10temp.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Clemens Ladisch <clemens@ladisch.de>
description:    AMD Family 10h+ CPU core temperature monitor
srcversion:     14A256DFDD079707B954390
alias:          pci:v00001D94d00001463sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000166Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000167Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d000014B0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001653sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001443sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000144Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001493sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d000015EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001463sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001583sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001533sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d000015B3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001573sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d0000141Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001403sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001603sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001703sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001303sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001022d00001203sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           k10temp
vermagic:       5.15.0-56-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        73:66:B8:30:4A:96:D1:13:0F:1A:D0:65:03:8A:0C:45:6A:06:9F:9E
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      72:90:DF:0C:08:A2:D2:E0:4D:2A:44:FD:E1:1D:6B:7B:AD:F4:88:84:
                3D:.I have shorted that.DD
parm:           force:force loading on processors with erratum 319 (bool)
```

In the bios and under Win10 the temperature is displayed correctly to me, so the error must be directly with Linux.
What is my problem here?
What can I do to get the CPU temperature displayed?
Does anyone of you have a solution or an idea how I can get further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in my then running kernel 5.15 there was no support for the new Zen4 CPUs yet.
Therefore I updated to kernel 6.00.
This article helped me to do that:
https://tipsonunix.com/2022/10/03/how-to-install-linux-kernel-6-0-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/